# Modeling pass rates for departments and courses within a school

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, multilevel-analysis

Suppose I have a regression model, for example a logistic regression model, which provides a score between 0 and 1 reflecting whether or not that a student will pass a course given certain variables:

- Variables about that student's demographics / past academic performance
- Variables describing the course, such as the course subject, whether it's a 100, 200, 300    level, etc. course, perhaps the previous term's pass rate for that course

and that the output of the logistic regression model is calibrated so that the response are, hopefully, reliable probabilities.

Taking a subset of the population, for example a department or a course, the expected pass rate for that subset should be the average of the probabilities output by the logistic for that subset, by linearity of expectation.

Is this a reasonable way of projecting pass rates for these subgroups, or should I expect these projected pass rates to be unreliable for some reason (e.g. the model is likely to be inaccurate for certain subpopulations even if the overall accuracy is quite good).

I've read some about multi-level modeling. Would that approach help to make these predictions for subpopulations be more reliable?

Also, I have historical pass rate data for each of the courses and departments, so I could possibly combine the projected pass rate based on the probabilities for each student in a course or department with some sort of projection of the pass rate based on the time-series of historical pass rates. Including this time-series information may help more on the department level where there are consistently large numbers of students.

Are there any other approaches you can recommend or flaws in the current approach you can point out?

Comment: Think you really have to consider the influence of individual professors on pass rate, not only department-specific dummies (no pun intended)...